# Which Eclipse version is good for building desktop application.?

Tags: java, eclipse

Which Eclipse version is good for building desktop application in java. ?

Am using **eclipse indigo** is it good.

Answer (score 1):

Get a modern version of Eclipse and install the [WindowBuilder Plugin](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201309271200/4.3/) or get a modern version of NetBeans and start by creating a new JFrame Form.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use Vim, it really doesn't matter. If you want to use the interface builder, you could use Eclipse or Netbeans.